# Cant select bones in edit mode

Tags: bones

I just added a human skeleton into the scene from rigify and I cant select the individual bones. Helllp!
https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cr6rbZVXRJs

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: According to the properties page, 'Group4.001' appears to be the active object whatever that is! If the armature was selected you wouldn't see the Vertex, Edge and Face icons on the top left of the toolbar. Can you [upload the blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help) so that we can have a look?

Comment: uploaded the file, hope I did that right. I'm trying to rig a skeleton, Group4 is the mesh. I've hidden it cause I thought it was strange the vertices were still showing despite having clicked the rig in the top right :\

Comment: I literally just closed blender and opened it back up with the file... and now I can select the individual bones. My brains gonna explode. Was this a bug or is there a proper way to select between the two I missed?

Comment: That works fine for me.

Comment: Select between which two? You have the metarig which I can select normally and a mesh of a skeleton which is disabled in the outliner.

Comment: the mesh and rig. I think this may have been a temporary bug or is there something else I need to do to make the rig the active object other than just left clicking it in the menu? Oh yeah, now that the rig is selected the mesh cant be selected. How do I switch between them properly?

Comment: ohhhh, you preselect it in object mode. Oof. Thanks xD

Comment: Yes. You always have to select an object in Object mode before you can work on it in Edit mode. You can't just switch objects in the outliner while in Edit mode and expect to be able to work on them immediately.